# Unable to resolve the 'UnboundLocalError' in python3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I am calculating two ratios: ratio1 and ratio2. They are calculated by using the key of a dictionary. If they do not find the key, they simply print it without an error.

```
    try:
            #RATIO FOR THE LEFT LEG
            ratio1 = distance(dict[x],dict[y]) 
            print(ratio1)
    except KeyError:
            print('Left Ratio Not Available')    

    try:
            #RATIO FOR THE RIGHT LEG    
            ratio2 = distance(dict[p],dict[q])
            print(ratio2)
    except KeyError:
            print('Right Ratio Not Available')
```

Till here my code works fine. But as I proceed to find the Max out of both the ratios,

```
    try:
            print('max ratio is : ', max(ratio1,ratio2))
    except KeyError:
            try:
                print(ratio1)
            except KeyError:
                try:
                    print(ratio2)
                finally:
                    print('No Ratio Available.')
```

I get 'UnboundLocalError'.

```
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ratio1' referenced before assignment
```

I even used 'global'. But either way, I am getting the same error. 
Please tell me how to handle this appropriately.

Comment: All this is part of a class. Just in case it suffices the need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your code works fine. The problem is that you catch a keyerror in the first try-except statement and move on to the next two try's. If the first one catches a KeyError and then you try to read from the variable called ratio1 then you get this kind of error because you didn't initiate the variable.

your code should look something like this:

```
try:
    # RATIO FOR THE LEFT LEG
    ratio1 = distance(dict[x],dict[y]) 
    print(ratio1)
except KeyError:
    ratio1 = 0
    print('Left Ratio Not Available')
try:
    # RATIO FOR THE RIGHT LEG    
    ratio2 = distance(dict[p],dict[q])
    print(ratio2)
except KeyError:
    ratio2 = 0
    print('Right Ratio Not Available')

print('max ratio is : ', max(ratio1,ratio2))
```